# Solution to the $\bar{\partial}-$ equation in $\mathbb{C}$ continuous up to the boundary

Tags: complex-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Given an open domain $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ it is known that given $\phi \in C^\infty(\Omega)$ one can solve the partial differential equation $\bar{\partial}u := \frac{\partial u}{\partial \bar{z}} = \phi$ in $\Omega$ to obtain a $u\in C^\infty(\Omega).$ Are there any special domains, say a rectangle or a disk, or extra conditions that can be imposed, say boundedness of $\phi$ so that the solution $u$ can also be taken to be continuous up to the boundary?

Comment: In $\mathbb{C}$, every domain is (strictly) pseudoconvex and hence the $\overline{\partial}$-problem can be solved. So I believe that the condition that you are looking for is not on the domain but rather on $\phi$. \href{https://books.google.com/books?id=MaM7AAAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&pg=PA3#v=onepage&q&f=false}{Theorem 1.2.2} gives us an explicit solution. So as long as the integral makes sense, we can obtain solution that are continuous up to the boundary. I am not an expert, so this might be wrong/missing important details.

Comment: @iota Thanks for the reference! Indeed, this seems to suggest that boundedness of $\phi$ and boundedness of $\Omega$ is good enough for a continuous extension to exist.